# sed multiline replace

Tags: sed, multiline

this is my sample text file :

```
asdas
//<<<TAG
this should be removed
//TAG>>>
this should be there
//<<<TAG
T
>
asd
asd
//TAG>>>
```

for which i want o/p as :

```
asdas

this should be there
```

Basically i m trying to find lines between "//<<>>" (including these lines too) and delete them.

I tried using sed

> sed -n
>   '1h;1!H;${;g;s///<<]*TAG>>>//g;p;}'
>   < test.txt

But some how it did not produced correct output. The second tag which contained ">" symbol failed in regex. Not sure where i m going wrong?

Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: In your output, are you sure you want a blank line between asdas and 'this should be there'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are trying to delete lines with the literal text 'TAG', try:

```
sed '/\/\/<<<TAG/,/\/\/TAG>>>/d'
```

From your comments, it appears that TAG may not be literal, in which case:

```
sed '/^\/\/<</,/^\/\/.*>>/d'
```

This can be simplified by using a different delimiter:

```
sed '@^//<<<@,@^//.*>>>@d'
```

Comment: Google searches for "sed one-liners" often are very helpful - http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt should be one of the first results, and contains this one among many others.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using the sed solution I gave, you might like either of these in perl and awk:

```
perl -ne 'print if !( m@//<<<TAG@ .. m@//TAG>>>@ )'
awk '/\/\/<<<TAG/,/\/\/TAG>>>/ {next} 1'
```

Given that I think you really do not want TAG to be a constant, the cleanest solution I know of is the perl variant:

```
perl -ne 'print if !( m@^//<<<(.*)@ .. m@^//$1>>>$@ )'
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition the search delimiters in `sed` can be changed by escaping the first delimiter:

```
sed '\|^//<<<|,\|^//.*>>>|d' file
```

---

Awk version the matches the end with the same tag name:

```
awk -F'//<<<|//|>>>' '$2{p=$2; while(getline && p!=$2); next}1' file
```