# sed conditional branching with multiline section

Tags: sed, branch, conditional-statements

I'm trying multiline replacement with sed for the first time.  I found a couple of good pointers out there ([general multiline help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string) and [multiline between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043363/sed-regexp-multiline-replace-html)).  Using this as a starter, I have the following command:

```
sed '
/<dependency>/,/<\/dependency>/ { # Find a set of lines for a dependency
    s/\(<artifactId>\)m[^<]*\(<\/artifactId>\)/\1ARTIFACTID\2/ # Substitute if artifactId starts with 'm'
    t depend-update # If we substituted, go to depend-update.  Otherwise, continue
    :depend-unchanged
    s/\(<groupId>\)[^<]*\(<\/groupId>\)/\1CHANGE_A\2/ # Change groupId to have 'A'
    b # branch to end
:depend-update
    s/\(<groupId>\)[^<]*\(<\/groupId>\)/\1CHANGE_B\2/ # Change groupID to have 'B'
    b # branch to end
}
' \
inputfile.xml
```

My input file has the following contents:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>test.a</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>mytest.a</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>baz</groupId>
    <artifactId>test.b</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Unfortunately, for all sections, I get "CHANGE_A".  As I understand it, this means that sed always thinks that the first replace did nothing, even though it did.  The result is:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>CHANGE_A</groupId>
            <artifactId>test.a</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>CHANGE_A</groupId>
            <artifactId>ARTIFACTID</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>CHANGE_A</groupId>
            <artifactId>test.b</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Multi line is due to the "problem" that sed work line by line on a strem/file input and not as a whole.
In your case you treat a pack of line but still 1 line at a time and not as a block

/startBlock/,/EndBlock/ mean just, treat all line inside those 2 delimiter, not group the block in 1 big block

Here is the adaptation proposed

```
sed '
/<dependency>/,\#</dependency># {
# load into the buffer
    /<dependency>/ h;/<dependency>/ !H
    \#</dependency># {
# At end of block, load the buffer and work on it
    g

# Find a set of lines for a dependency
        s/\(<artifactId>\)m[^<]*\(<\/artifactId>\)/\1ARTIFACTID\2/ # Substitute if artifactId starts with 'm'
        t depend-update # If we substituted, go to depend-update.  Otherwise, continue
:depend-unchanged
        s/\(<groupId>\)[^<]*\(<\/groupId>\)/\1CHANGE_A\2/ # Change groupId to have 'A'
# branch to end
        b # branch to end
:depend-update
        s/\(<groupId>\)[^<]*\(<\/groupId>\)/\1CHANGE_B\2/ # Change groupID to have 'B'
# branch to end
        b
        }
    }
' \
inputfile.xml
```