# Sed expression to match this multiline code?

Tags: sed

Assume the following code snippet:

```
  <head>
     <script>....</script>
     <script>....</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      some stuff
      a change
      more stuff
      more changes
      more stuff
            }
          }
        }
      }
     final changes
    </script>
  </body>
```

I need to add something right before the last `</script>`, what's stated as `final changes`. How can I tell sed to match that one? `final changes` doesn't exist, the last lines of the script are like four or five `}`, so it would be the scenario, I'd need to match multiple lines.

All the other changes were replaced by matching the line, then replacing with the `line + the changes`. But I don't know how to match the multi line to replace`</script></body>` with `final changes </script></body>`.

I tried to use the same tactic I use for replacing with multiple lines, but it didn't work, keep reporting `unterminated substitute pattern`.

```
sed 's|</script>\
   </body>|lalalalala\
   </script>\
   </body>|' file.hmtl
```

I've read this question [Sed regexp multiline - replace HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043363/sed-regexp-multiline-replace-html) but it doesn't suit my particular case because it matches everything between the search options. I need to match something, then add something before the first search operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this following xara's answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string

In summary, instead of trying to do magic with sed, replace the newlines with a character which sed understands (like `\r`), do the replace and then replace the character with newline again.

Answer (score 1):

`sed`, `grep`, `awk` etc. are NOT for XML/HTML processing.
Use a proper XML/HTML parsers.

**`xmlstarlet`** is one of them.
Sample `file.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
     <script>....</script>
     <script>....</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var data = [0, 1, 2];
      console.log(data);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

The command:

```
xmlstarlet ed -O -P -u '//body/script' -v 'alert("success")' file.htm
```

The output:

```
<html>
<head>
     <script>....</script>
     <script>....</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>alert("success")</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html

Comment: I agree that `xmlstarlet` is the way to go, but unfortunately, as with `jq`, there are only 3 people in the universe who know how to use either! Do you know of any good resources that explain how to use it which are intelligible to mortals, please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, no problem, added xmlstarlet guide link

Comment: this solution is correct if I want to replace the content between specific tags, that is a HTML parser. But this is not my case, I'm not parsing HTML, I'm interested in replacing specific strings within a file (it really won't matter whether it's HTML, C++ or just a random text file). Check the edited snippet in the  question.