# sed multiline delete with pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I want to delete all multiline occurences of a pattern like

```
  {START-TAG
  foo bar
  ID: 111
  foo bar
  END-TAG}

  {START-TAG
  foo bar
  ID: 222
  foo bar
  END-TAG}

  {START-TAG
  foo bar
  ID: 333
  foo bar
  END-TAG}
```

I want to delete all portions between START-TAG and END-TAG that contain specific IDs.

So to delete ID: 222 only this would remain:

```
  {START-TAG
  foo bar 2
  ID: 111
  foo bar 3
  END-TAG}


  {START-TAG
  foo bar 2
  ID: 333
  foo bar 3
  END-TAG}
```

I have a blacklist of IDs that should be removed.

I assume a quite simple multiline sed regex script would do it. Can anyone help?

It is very similar to Question: [sed multiline replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221245/sed-multiline-replace) but not the same.

Comment: Difficult using `sed`, since the `ID` is in the middle of the section to be deleted. Much easier using `awk`.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs not overly difficult `sed '/{START-TAG/{:1;/END-TAG}/!{N;b1};/ID: *222/d}'` ?

Comment: @123 A matter of opinion, of course. I find `sed` branching too slippery to handle. And it's surely more difficult than `awk -v RS="" '!/ID: 222/'`.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs `delete all portions between START-TAG and END-TAG`, big assumption to make that there will always be a blank line between. Also the sed command would be simpler if i also made that assumption.

Comment: @123 Point conceded.

Comment: Just use awk for portability, robustness, etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62471543/1745001

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
sed '/{START-TAG/{:a;N;/END-TAG}/!ba};/ID: 222/d' data.txt
```

Breakdown:

```
/{START-TAG/ { # Match '{START-TAG'
:a             # Create label a
N              # Read next line into pattern space
/END-TAG}/!    # If not matching 'END-TAG}'...
           ba  # Then goto a
}              # End /{START-TAG/ block
/ID: 222/d     # If pattern space matched 'ID: 222' then delete it.
```

Comment: What about a list of IDs? Is there a common sed trick for this ? Or would I use a bash-for loop? Ah .,, sed -F with a list of such patterns/commands ?

Comment: Replace last line with something like this: `/ID: \(a\|b\|c\)/d`. Where `a`, `b`,  and `c` are the ID's you want to delete.

Comment: Is it possible to reuse this in order to comment, add # in front of every line on the block than delete?

Comment: @QuinnComendant no it doesn't. Your posted example is nearly identical, only difference is that the start tag line is also checked to see if it's the end tag line, where mine reads the next line immediatly.

Comment: Oh, you're right – I had an error in the code I was testing. Your does as expected, and since my comment is irrelevant, I'll delete it. 

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sed` for anything that involves multiple lines, just use `awk` for a robust, portable solution. Given the sample input from the question you referenced, if the blocks are always separated by blank lines:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!/ID: 222/' file
  {START-TAG
  foo bar
  ID: 111
  foo bar
  END-TAG}

  {START-TAG
  foo bar
  ID: 333
  foo bar
  END-TAG}
```

Otherwise:

```
$ awk '/{START-TAG/{f=1} f{rec=rec $0 ORS} /END-TAG}/{if (rec !~ /ID: 222/) print rec; rec=f=""}' file
  {START-TAG
  foo bar
  ID: 111
  foo bar
  END-TAG}

  {START-TAG
  foo bar
  ID: 333
  foo bar
  END-TAG}
```