# Bash Delete Between Patterns With Regex And Variables

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I need to delete all occurrences from a txt file based on a pattern. Part of the pattern is a variable.

Here is what the txt file looks like:

```
#start_pattern_dhhr6783-rhr.variable.1#
some line here     
    some other line here
    some other line here
    new line goes here
#end_pattern_dhhr6783-rhr.variable.1

#start_pattern_variable.2#
some line here     
    some other line here
    some other line here
    new line goes here
#end_pattern_variable2

#start_pattern_7hbdhy-hjruy_hry673.variable.3#
some line here     
    some other line here
    some other line here
    new line goes here
#end_pattern_7hbdhy-hjruy_hry673.variable.3

#start_pattern_variable.4#
some line here     
    some other line here
    some other line here
    new line goes here
#end_pattern_variable4

#start_pattern_variable.3#
some line here     
    some other line here
    some other line here
    new line goes here
#end_pattern_variable.3

#start_pattern_498595-hjfufr7.variable.3#
some line here     
    some other line here
    some other line here
    new line goes here
#end_pattern_498595-hjfufr7.variable.3
```

Here is what I tried to do:

```
pattern="variable.3"

sed -n "/^#start*$pattern/,/^#end*$pattern/d"  /root/file.txt
sed -n "/#start*$pattern/,/#end*$pattern/d"  /root/file.txt
sed -n "/^#start*\$pattern/,/^#end*\$pattern/d"  /root/file.txt
sed -n "/^#start.*$pattern/,/^#end.*$pattern/d"  /root/file.txt
sed -n '/^#start*"$pattern"/,/^#end*"$pattern"/d'  /root/file.txt
sed -n '/^#start_pattern_*"$pattern"/,/^#end_pattern_*"$pattern"/d'  /root/file.txt
```

BUT NONE OF THEM WORKS. Output is same as it was, so nothing happens. Already tried this on 3 linux machines, and nothing happens, there is no modification of the file.

What I want is to **delete all occurrences between the pattern** that does contain variable "variable.3"

It should match all this 3 results:

```
#start_pattern_7hbdhy-hjruy_hry673.variable.3#....

#start_pattern_variable.3#....

#start_pattern_498595-hjfufr7.variable.3#....
```

Comment: only code formatting, the sample doesn't have white space before the #start and #end tags

Comment: Never use the word `pattern` in this context as it's ambiguous. Always use the word `string` or `regexp`, whichever it is you really mean, instead. In your case you do not want the `.` in `variable.3` treated as a regexp metacharacter so clearly you mean to search for a string, not a regexp. Since sed cannot search for strings, only regexps, you therefore should not be considering using sed for this task, use awk (which DOES support string operations) instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed multiline delete with pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680636/sed-multiline-delete-with-pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you in same. This should remove the lines between patterns as well as it will remove the empty lines too from output.

```
awk -v val="variable.3" '
/#start/ && $0 ~ val{
  no_print=1
}
/#start/ && $0 !~ val{
  no_print=""
}
!no_print && NF
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
    #start_pattern_dhhr6783-rhr.variable.1#
    some line here
    some other line here
    some other line here
    new line goes here
    #end_pattern_dhhr6783-rhr.variable.1
    #start_pattern_variable.2#
    some line here
    some other line here
    some other line here
    new line goes here
    #end_pattern_variable2
    #start_pattern_variable.4#
    some line here
    some other line here
    some other line here
    new line goes here
    #end_pattern_variable4
```

You could give the value of variable in `-v val` to change it as per your need too. Also in case you need empty lines in output then you change condition `!no_print && NF` to `!no_print` and it should fly then.

One could change from `$0 ~ val` to `index($0,val)` to avoid false matches. THANKS to Ed Morton sir for their views. More details could be found on this post's comment section.

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation of code too now:

```
awk -v val="variable.3" '    ##Setting variable named val value to variable.3 here.
/#start/ && $0 ~ val{        ##Checking condition here if a line is having string #start in it and it is having variable val in it too then do following:
  no_print=1                 ##Setting variable named no_print value to TRUE.
}
/#start/ && $0 !~ val{       ##Checking condition here if a line is having string #start and it is NOT having variable val in it then do following:
  no_print=""                ##Setting variable no_print to NULL here.
}
!no_print && NF              ##Checking condition here if variable no_print is NULL and NF(number of fields in a line, awk out of the box variable) is NOT NULL
                             ##then print those lines, basically this condition is to print those lines which are NOT coming in the block of variable pattern.
' Input_file                 ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @user2627132, your welcome, always glad to help and learn here, cheers :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 : Nice explanation!! ,One thing to ask..what's the role of `no_print` in the script, is it `awk`'s utility or a separate variable defined to print or not print the lines?

Comment: @User123, thanks. No, as mentioned in explanation it is a variable used in awk program. So as it's name suggests it will not print lines when it's value will be TRUE.

Comment: That will produce false matches due to using a regexp instead of string comparison.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure Ed sir, would like to request you could you either please edit it with correct one or guide me here on this, will be grateful to you sir.

Comment: Change `$0 ~ val` to `index($0,val)` or provide a mechanism to escape all possible regexp metacharacters in `val` (not recommended!) or tell the OP to escape the regexp metacharacters manually before calling the script.

Comment: @EdMorton, just added a fair warning/statement in answer now too and mentioned to see the this post's comment section for my details, thanks a TON for your as usual guidance, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is making it much more complicated than it has to be. All you really need is:

```
awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' -F'\n' -v str='variable.3' '!index($1,str)' file
```

Note that the above is also more robust than using a regexp which would need to have the metacharacters in your search string (e.g. `.`) escaped.