# Delete the whole xml tag using the sed command

Tags: xml, sed

I want to delete the whole xml tag including the content . But only the first 2 lines are getting deleted. sed or awk is okay

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                   maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
                   username="javauser" password="javadude" 
                             driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                             url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>
```

After trying out the sed command  `sed -i "/Resource/,/[^\/>]/d" test.xml`

I am left over with

```
  username="javauser" password="javadude" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>
```

Comment: *sed or awk is okay* - they are bad here. Post an extended input fragment

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed multiline delete with pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680636/sed-multiline-delete-with-pattern)

Comment: It is an irony that the right tool for the job which is `xmlstarlet`  is not in the tags. Remember this - `jq is sed for json` and `xmlstarlet is sed for xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want

`sed '/<Resource /{:a;N;/\/>/!ba};/<Resource/d' test.html`

Comment: comment Appreciate a lot for your help with this

Comment: sed '/<Resource /,/\/>/d' is enough.

Answer (score 1):

With xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet edit --delete '//path/to/your/tag' file.xml
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The right too for the job is`xmlstartlet`.