# Bash script iterate through file and delete block of text using sed

Tags: json, bash, shell, sed

I have a JSON file with the following contents:

```
[
    {
        "url" : "www.google.com",
        "valid_from" : "            Jul 31 10:16:13 2017 GMT",
        "valid_till" : "            Jul 31 10:16:13 2019 GMT",
        "validity" : "Valid",
        "days" : "464"
    },
    {
        "url" : "www.youtube.com",
        "valid_from" : "            Apr  9 12:12:17 2017 GMT",
        "valid_till" : "            Apr  9 12:12:17 2019 GMT",
        "validity" : "Valid",
        "days" : "351"
    }
]
```

I want to delete a block of JSON by passing a url argument corresponding to the block to delete.
I have a script `cert-check-script-delete.sh` which contains the following code:

```
line_num=1

cat certs.json >> certs-new.json

while read p; do  # Iterate through each line in certs.json
    if [[ $p == *"$1"* ]];   # Check if current line contains argument
    then
        sed -i "${line_num-1}d" certs-new.json  # {
        sed -i "${line_num}d"   certs-new.json  # Url
        sed -i "${line_num+1}d" certs-new.json  # Valid from
        sed -i "${line_num+2}d" certs-new.json  # Valid till
        sed -i "${line_num+3}d" certs-new.json  # Validity
        sed -i "${line_num+4}d" certs-new.json  # Days
        sed -i "${line_num+5}d" certs-new.json  # }
        break
    fi
    ((line_num++))
done <certs.json

mv certs-new.json certs.json
```

And after running my script with argument `www.youtube.com` I'm getting weird behaviour where it seems to just be deleting random lines:

```
    {
        "valid_from" : "            Jul 31 10:16:13 2017 GMT",
        "validity" : "Valid",
    {
        "valid_till" : "            Apr  9 12:12:17 2019 GMT",
        "validity" : "Valid",
        "days" : "351"
    }
]
```

I know I should use `jq` for inserting/deleting JSON but I'm not able to install it at work, so please don't just comment saying use `jq`.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It is not `js` it is `jq` and why wouldn't you want to use that?

Comment: Can you use `perl` atleast

Comment: You could change your logic a bit.  Read line per line and copy the lines into an output file.  When you hit a "{", stop copying lines.  The next line is then verified to see if it matches your URL.  It does?  Stop copying until you hit a "}".  Otherwise, keep copying in the output file.  And then there is the `,` to consider...  It's doable, but really there are much easier solutions out there (language and/or tool).

Comment: yeah, why not use json parser? with `jq`, it might be something like `jq -r 'map(select(."url" != "www.youtube.com"))'`

Comment: @Inian I'm writing this app at work and am not allowed to download and run the jq `.exe`. Is there a way to install it via Git Bash/cmd?

Comment: @Sundeep I'm writing this app at work and am not allowed to download and run the jq .exe. Is there a way to install it via Git Bash/cmd?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed multiline delete with pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680636/sed-multiline-delete-with-pattern)

Comment: If your employer will not allow you to use the correct tool for the job, you need to educate your employer.  If that fails, you find a new employer.

Comment: @WilliamPursell we require admin rights to install software through `.exe` files, seems reasonable tbf

Comment: For what it's worth, running multiple `sed -i` on the same file in a loop is the mother of all antipatterns. You should nearly always be able to refactor to use a single `sed` script; and if not, see if there is a way to restructure the code so that you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
 sed -i '/www.youtube.com/I,+6 d;$!N;/www.youtube.com/!P;D' certs-new.json
```

If your search string has been provided as command line parameter use like

```
sed -i '/'$1'/I,+6 d;$!N;/'$1'/!P;D' certs-new.json
```

How will it work, First it will search for pattern `www.youtube.com` and delete 6 lines below the pattern and second part of `sed` command will search for pattern `www.youtube.com` and delete the pattern line and one line above it.

In your example the output will be:-

```
[
{
    "url" : "www.google.com",
    "valid_from" : "            Jul 31 10:16:13 2017 GMT",
    "valid_till" : "            Jul 31 10:16:13 2019 GMT",
    "validity" : "Valid",
    "days" : "464"
},
]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but when I try to replace the url in the command with the argument variable it doesn't do anything. I've tried replacing the `www.youtube.com` in the command with `$1`, `{$1}` and `"$1"`

Comment: Use double quote like sed -i "/$1/I,+6 d;$!N;/$1/!P;D"

Comment: Thank you! Very nice 1 line solution. Just one issue, when I do it on Youtube it works fine but when I do it on Google it deletes Youtube's opening bracket, any idea why?

Comment: probably some space use `+5 d` instead of `+6 d` and check

Comment: hi, this works fine when there's more than 1 JSON entry in the file, but when there's just 1 it leaves only the last 2 brackets `}]` instead of the first and last bracket `[]`, any ideas why this is happening?