# Mutiline delete in FreeBSD

Tags: sed, freebsd

How can we make this work in FreeBSD?

Multiple line delete block containing a pattern in FreeBSD.

```
sed '/{START-TAG/{:a;N;/END-TAG}/!ba};/ID: 222/d' data.txt
```

See
[sed multiline delete with pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680636/sed-multiline-delete-with-pattern/37681075#37681075).

Comment: See the solution by [Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62496830/6482561).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FreeBSD `sed`, you can't separate commands using a semi-colon. However, you may use `-e` chained commands:

```
sed -e '/{START-TAG/{' -e :a -e N -e '/END-TAG}/!ba' -e '}' -e '/ID: 222/d' file > outputfile
```

To save the contents inline, use

```
sed -i '' -e '/{START-TAG/{' -e :a -e N -e '/END-TAG}/!ba' -e '}' -e '/ID: 222/d' file
```

Comment: This doesn't work... I mean, it doesn't do what the question asked for...

Comment: @IsmaelLuceno It is the exact same command as `sed '/{START-TAG/{:a;N;/END-TAG}/!ba};/ID: 222/d' data.txt`. Just what OP asked for.

Comment: Besides, I tested the two commands and they yield identical output.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use sed for anything that involves multiple lines, just use awk for a robust, portable solution. Given the sample input from [the question you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37680636/1745001), if the blocks are always separated by blank lines:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!/ID: 222/' file
  {START-TAG
  foo bar
  ID: 111
  foo bar
  END-TAG}

  {START-TAG
  foo bar
  ID: 333
  foo bar
  END-TAG}
```

otherwise:

```
$ awk '/{START-TAG/{f=1} f{rec=rec $0 ORS} /END-TAG}/{if (rec !~ /ID: 222/) print rec; rec=f=""}' file
  {START-TAG
  foo bar
  ID: 111
  foo bar
  END-TAG}

  {START-TAG
  foo bar
  ID: 333
  foo bar
  END-TAG}
```

Both of those scripts will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box.